# Go gin - fetch data from local browser

Tags: javascript, http, go, fetch-api, content-security-policy

I have a simple server written with Go Gin:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.GET("/", func(context *gin.Context) {
        context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"hello": "world"})
    })

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

If I do a `fetch` from Firefox console (97.0.2 (64-bit) on Ubuntu):

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8080/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I get the following error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8080/ 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

While, if I do the same HTTP GET request from a terminal with **curl**, I get the correct result:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/

{"hello":"world"}
```

Is it possible to test the Go gin server using the browser?

Comment: @mkopriva The error message doesn't mention CORS, though.

Comment: @jub0bs you're right, my bad, I misread it.

Comment: @mkopriva According to `gin-contrib/cors` documentation, cors is handled by `router.Use(cors.Default())`

Comment: @AndreaGrillo yup, apologies, I skimmed your question and made wrong assumptions.

Comment: @AndreaGrillo what you can do is to have the gin app serve an /index page (can be empty HTML, i.e. empty handler), then navigate to that page and from there open the console and execute your `fetch` from there. https://imgur.com/a/eKhFZck

Comment: Thank you, it works! Why do I need the /index page? Is it related to the `Origin` property of HTTP header?

Comment: You actually don't need /index, you can also just navigate to `http://localhost:8080/` and open the console there and fetch from there. The /index is just an arbitrary location. What's important is that the location from which you fetch is under the same domain as the location which you fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to do ajax request from different location then the request request location then the request will be blocked by `Content Security Policy (CSP)` which help to detect and mitigate certain types of attacks. You can read more about CSP [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

For [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to work you have to go to the same location and make [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) request from that location in your case it is `http://localhost:8080/`.

Note: Since you have defined the root route to return json when you open the location in browser which may raise a GET request and the response json will be returned in browser.